# How do I implement a WCF Streaming operation that streams data in, processes it, streams it back(with MessageContracts)?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, stream, messagecontract

I have a requirement for a WCF service operation that accepts a large Stream, processes it and returns that stream.

I used [an MSDN article on Large Data Streaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) as a reference to what I need. I followed the advice in that article.

Asking the question in advance:

1. **I would like to know why the generated service operation does not have a return type when I specified it in the contract?**
2. **If that is expected behaviour, how should I get it to pass on a stream and return a processed stream?**

**Details**:

Because I need to accompany both the input and return streams with MetaData, I decorated the classes with MessageContract attributes, as is required.

Here is a brief run-down of my implementation:

**Message Contracts:**

```
[MessageContract]
public class InputStreamMessage
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public InputStreamHeader Header { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream Data { get; set; }

}

[MessageContract]
public class OutputStreamMessage
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public OutputStreamHeader Header { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream Data { get; set; }

}
```

**Service Contract:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStreamService
{
    [OperationContract]
    OutputStreamMessage ProcessStream(InputStreamMessage input);
}
```

**Service Implementation:**

```
 public OutputStreamMessage DoStreamOperation(InputStreamMessage input)
 {
    //Some logic that assigns re
    OutputStreamMessage output = DoSomeNonBufferedProcessing(input);

    return output;
 }
```

**Client-side:**

On the client-side, I then generate the service reference, and call the service as below:

```
private void PerformStreamOperation()
{
    try
    {
        //
        StreamServiceReference.StreamServiceClient client = new StreamServiceReference.StreamServiceReferenceClient();
        client.Open();

        //Set Header and Parameters
        InputMessageHeader header = new InputMessageHeader();

        //...                
        //... initialize header data here
        //...                

        //... do some operation to get input stream
        var inputstream = SomeOperationToGetInputStream();

        //Perform Service stream action
        //         ____ [ Why does the generated method have the following signature, retuning void?]
        //        |     [ If this is expected, how do I use it? ]
        //        |
        //        V 
        client.DoStreamOperation(header, ref inputstream); 


        //...                
        //... Do what you wish with data
        //...                

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Stream Processing Error");
    }
}
```

The MSDN article uses the exact same contract that exists in the [official WCF samples.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483346%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Stream EchoStream(Stream data)

But no example of an equivalent MessageContract implementation. The sample version does an expected return.

**Update**

- I noticed that the service reference has Task/Asynchronous methods that are generated with the expected method signature. Maybe that means when using MessageContract with a Stream property, returning a similarly structured object, then you will have to call it Asynchronously. I have not seen it documented anywhere. Will try using the methods - **Did not work as we want synchronous operations.**
- I have also tried using the `ChannelFactory` as an alternative to the generated proxy client:

  ```
    EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9910/StreamService");

    channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IStreamService>("netTcpStreamedEndPoint");
    channelFactory.Endpoint.Contract.SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed;
    IStreamService service = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
  ```

Comment: Have you tried using `ChannelFactory` instead of adding a service reference, might help to show where the problem lies.

Comment: Yes, I have used ChannelFactory. will place an update

Comment: Ok and what was the result of using `ChannelFactory`, have you tried switching on tracing and seeing if any errors pop up?

Comment: Will update the question with what I have tried

Answer (score 2):

Im sorry for replying in an answer (I dont have reputation for comments).

I am working on simmilar project as you are - I have service, that accepts large stream of data (using MessageContracts), process it and then client can download these data.

First of all - the input parameters at:

```
 client.DoStreamOperation(header, ref inputstream);
```

shows, that it seems like you did not generated service proxy with MessageContracts included (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2008/05/13/windows-communication-foundation-wcf-what-the-hell-is-always-generate-message-contracts.aspx). That should provide you OutputStreamMessage and InputStreamMessage contracts on client side.

With messageContracts properly generated, I can write both of these in my code, without receiving compile error:

```
client.DoStreamOperation(inputStreamMessage)
```

and

```
   StreamServiceReference.StreamServiceClient.OutputStreamMessage outputMessage = client.DoStreamOperation(inputStreamMessage)
```

But basicaly the first one has no use.
And of course I have to create InputStreamMessage object first:

```
StreamServiceReference.StreamServiceClient.InputStreamMessage inputStreamMessage = new StreamServiceReference.StreamServiceClient.InputStreamMessage();
```

If you would like, I can post some samples of my MessageContracts.

Also, please take a look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP . My messagecontracs looked simmilar at the early stage of the project

---

EDIT:
The session mode is set like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

The reason for that is that I need to maintain information(state) about objects, that are common for multiple clients. But this should not affect streaming.

Here is my binding. Im using basic http:

```
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransferBinding" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="10067108864">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

For uploading, Im using this kind of messagecontract:

```
    [MessageContract]
        public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
        {
            [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
            public string FileName;

            [MessageBodyMember]
            public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;
}
```

This is the body of method defined at client-side, that calls StartUpload() defines at service side (You need to define filePath that leads to the file you want to upload):

```
using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
                           // start service client
                CalculationServiceClient client = new CalculationServiceClient();     

                RemoteFileInfo remoteFileInfo = new RemoteFileInfo(); ;
                remoteFileInfo.FileName = TextBox1.Text;
                remoteFileInfo.FileByteStream = stream;

                // upload file
                client.StartUpload(remoteFileInfo);

                // close service client
                client.Close();
                uploadStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

Then, I define StartUpload() operationContract at service side. The inside of StartUpload contract looks for example like this:

```
public void StartUpload(RemoteFileInfo fileInfo)
        {

            string filePath = define your filePath, where you want to save the file;           

            int chunkSize = 2048;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];

            using (System.IO.FileStream writeStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
            {
                do
                {
                    // read bytes from input stream (provided by client)
                    int bytesRead =  fileInfo.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
                    if (bytesRead == 0) break;

                    // write bytes to output stream
                    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                } while (true);

                writeStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi @JakubJ. Thanks for replying. Would you mind posting an example implementation? What `SessionMode` did you also use and how is your binding config? Is it a continuous stream of data or do you close it at some point at the service operation? The codeproject article isnt what I am looking for though. I would like to send and return a continuous, unbroken stream

Comment: Hello. What do you exactly mean by continuous stream? Like if you are streaming live video for example? Iam using stream to transfer big files - client chooses file to transfer, hit "Upload" button and the whole file gets streamed to service side. I will update my answer in few minutes with some implementation I have.

Comment: I mean there is no break in the stream. As I stream in input, it gets processed, and returned on the go. Similar to the generally used method signature `void ProcessStream(Stream input, Stream output)` where `ProcessStream` processes and writes the processed `input` stream byte by byte to `output`. No `Stream.Close()` inside operation. This is fine in the context of one application. But entirely different with WCF. The catch is, with `transferMode=Streamed`, you can have one, and only one parameter(either a raw `Stream` or something composite within a `MessageContract`).

Comment: Oh I see...so you basically dont want to divide it to 3 steps: Upload (stop),Process data (stop),Download data, right?  I have updated my post with some code I have, but I did not realized you want something else, than I have implemented. Iam afraid I dont know how to implement the scenario you need.